# twig debug what does % mean - name of page.twig

Tags: theming, 8

I wonder about the "%". What does that mean?

```
<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'page' -->
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
  * page--node--31.html.twig
  * page--node--%.html.twig
  * page--node.html.twig
  x page.html.twig
-->
```

And what names are possible? I need a page for a specific and custom block for viewing the whole content.
I need something like this, but do not know how to do it right.

```
page--node--[my-custom-block]
```

Comment: I don't understand completely; how do you want to use page template for displaying a custom block? Can you clarify that part?

Comment: I had a block at sidebar. And in this sidebar are some articles. But only the teaser is visible. If you click the READ MORE-button a seperate page with whole content of article open. And for this page I want to make a seperate look. Therefore I need another page.twig

Comment: That means that you want separate page for nodes of certain content type; is that correct?

Comment: yes, that is right

Comment: Hmm, is there really nobody outside knowing well the naming conventions for templates in Drupal? How to name this separate page and what does the "%" mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
page--node--%.html.twig
```

This would be a universal template for page level views of any content type.  So if you wanted to have the same template for different content types you could use this convention.  If you need different templates for each content type you could apply:

```
page--node--[content type machine name].html.twig
```